# Significado de símbolo flecha en Python

Tags: python

Estoy interesado en el framework [Textual](https://textual.textualize.io) de Python y encontré definiciones de funciones con la forma:

```py
def action_toggle_dark(self) -> None:
    """An action to toggle dark mode."""
    self.dark = not self.dark
```

No sé si el símbolo `->` es propio de Python o es introducido por el framework, tampoco sé qué significa.

Comment: Hola! Se utiliza para especificar el retorno que va a tener esa función en específica y en este caso, el retorno que va a tener esta funcion va a ser none. Acá te dejo la documentación por cualquier cosa [Python Type Hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html)

Comment: Ah ok muchas gracias, nunca lo habia visto...

Comment: Es documentación; no afecta la ejecución del código.  Sirve para que las herramientas de revisión (pylint y otras) puedan revisar mejor el código.

Comment: Como te dijeron, no afecta la ejecución del código, pero es buena idea usarlos. Se ha estado poniendo de moda el tipado estricto de variables y valores de retorno en lenguajes que antes eran unicamente dinámicos: PHP lo tiene implementado en POO, JS con su implementación Typescript. No sería de extrañar que en algún momento se volviera un estándar en Python.